# JavaFX 8 Dynamic Node scaling

Tags: javafx-8, scaling, zooming

I'm trying to implement a scene with a `ScrollPane` in which the user can drag a node around and scale it dynamically. I have the dragging and scaling with the mouse wheel working as well as a reset zoom, but I'm having trouble with the calculations to fit the node to the width of the parent.

Here is my code as an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

1. (works) Mouse wheel will zoom in and out around the mouse pointer
2. (works) Left or right mouse press to drag the rectangle around
3. (works) Left double-click to reset the zoom
4. (doesn't work) Right double-click to fit the width

If I zoom in or out or change the window size, the fit to width does not work.

If anyone can help me with the calculations to fit the node to the width of the parent, I would very much appreciate it.

***EDITED:***

- I marked the method that is not working correctly. It is `fitWidth()`, which is invoked by right mouse button double-clicking.
- I edited the text of the question for clarity and focus

Hopefully this is more clear now.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ZoomAndPanExample extends Application {

    private ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

    private final DoubleProperty zoomProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0d);
    private final DoubleProperty deltaY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0d);

    private final Group group = new Group();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        scrollPane.setPannable(true);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(80, 60);

        rect.setStroke(Color.NAVY);
        rect.setFill(Color.NAVY);
        rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);

        group.getChildren().add(rect);
        // create canvas
        PanAndZoomPane panAndZoomPane = new PanAndZoomPane();
        zoomProperty.bind(panAndZoomPane.myScale);
        deltaY.bind(panAndZoomPane.deltaY);
        panAndZoomPane.getChildren().add(group);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(panAndZoomPane);

        scrollPane.setContent(panAndZoomPane);
        panAndZoomPane.toBack();
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseClickedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        root.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class PanAndZoomPane extends Pane {

        public static final double DEFAULT_DELTA = 1.3d;
        DoubleProperty myScale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
        public DoubleProperty deltaY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        private Timeline timeline;


        public PanAndZoomPane() {

            this.timeline = new Timeline(60);

            // add scale transform
            scaleXProperty().bind(myScale);
            scaleYProperty().bind(myScale);
        }


        public double getScale() {
            return myScale.get();
        }

        public void setScale( double scale) {
            myScale.set(scale);
        }

        public void setPivot( double x, double y, double scale) {
            // note: pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            // timeline that scales and moves the node
            timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(translateXProperty(), getTranslateX() - x)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(translateYProperty(), getTranslateY() - y)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(myScale, scale))
            );
            timeline.play();

        }

    /** 
     * !!!! The problem is in this method  !!!!
     * 
     * The calculations are incorrect, and result in unpredictable behavior
     *   
     */
        public void fitWidth () {
            double scale = getParent().getLayoutBounds().getMaxX()/getLayoutBounds().getMaxX();
            double oldScale = getScale();

            double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;

            double dx = getTranslateX() - getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2;
            double dy = getTranslateY() - getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2;

            double newX = f*dx + getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
            double newY = f*dy + getBoundsInParent().getMinY();

            setPivot(newX, newY, scale);

        }

        public void resetZoom () {
            double scale = 1.0d;

            double x = getTranslateX();
            double y = getTranslateY();

            setPivot(x, y, scale);
        }

        public double getDeltaY() {
            return deltaY.get();
        }
        public void setDeltaY( double dY) {
            deltaY.set(dY);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
     */
    class DragContext {

        double mouseAnchorX;
        double mouseAnchorY;

        double translateAnchorX;
        double translateAnchorY;

    }

    /**
     * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
     */
    public class SceneGestures {

        private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

        PanAndZoomPane panAndZoomPane;

        public SceneGestures( PanAndZoomPane canvas) {
            this.panAndZoomPane = canvas;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseClickedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseClickedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
            return onMousePressedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
            return onScrollEventHandler;
        }

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getX();
                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getY();

                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = panAndZoomPane.getTranslateX();
                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = panAndZoomPane.getTranslateY();

            }

        };

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                panAndZoomPane.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                panAndZoomPane.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

                event.consume();
            }
        };

        /**
         * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
         */
        private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

                double delta = PanAndZoomPane.DEFAULT_DELTA;

                double scale = panAndZoomPane.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
                double oldScale = scale;

                panAndZoomPane.setDeltaY(event.getDeltaY()); 
                if (panAndZoomPane.deltaY.get() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
                } else {
                    scale *= delta;
                }

                double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;

                double dx = (event.getX() - (panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
                double dy = (event.getY() - (panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));

                panAndZoomPane.setPivot(f*dx, f*dy, scale);

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        /**
         * Mouse click handler
         */
        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseClickedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        panAndZoomPane.resetZoom();
                    }
                }
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        panAndZoomPane.fitWidth();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @royhowie No, it will be closed if it is posted on Code Review because it is not working properly.

Comment: @Hosch250 your question makes it sound as though everything works (roughly) and certain aspects just need refinement

Comment: It isn't my question, and I am a regular at Code Review, and I believe this question is off topic because the calculations are not working as expected.  Code Review is for improving working code - it won't help anyone if we make his code be wrong better.

Comment: @royhowie as it stands it's not clear that the code works as intended *to the best of OP's knowledge* - this would be inviting close votes on CR. I suggest OP [edit] this question so that *the code block* itself is a SSCCE.

Comment: The question is broad and not highly focused (eg. what is wrong with this?) and there is a substantial amount of code to review (I'm not sure that it qualifies as a SSCCE).  It may be more useful to you to refine your question to reduce the burden of review.

Comment: OK, I put some comments in the code to denote the method that doesn't work correctly. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: hmm... what about the zoom, does that behave as you expect? For me, this moving and zooming at the same time doesn't feel right: I would expect an in-place zoom. And don't quite understand what you expect the fit to do?  Unzoomed, it always fills its parent in both directions, no matter what its aspect ratio ...

Comment: actually, the fit (unzoomed) does about what I would expect (stretch to the width while trying to keep aspect ratio) if the width of the rect is about 4*height. On the whole, the question should be clearer on what exactly you expect, that is what the "to get it right" means to you :-)

Comment: The zooming occurs around the mouse pointer, so it would appear to zoom in all directions based on the location of the pointer. Also, It is true that if you do not move the rectangle at all, and simply invoke fit to width. it appears to work well. However, the problem comes in when the rectangle is not at coordinates 0,0 and/or is scaled to greater or less than 1:1. Please try dragging the rectangle around the pane, zooming in or out, and resizing the window and let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I was looking at the wrong calculations, assuming it to be related to the translations. The real culprit was the calculation for the difference in scale. I simply changed this:

`double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;`

to this:

`double f = scale - oldScale;`