# How to zoom a pdf to the mouse position in javafx 2

Tags: pdf, javafx-2, zooming

I have to zoom a pdf-file thats inside of a ScrollPane.
The ScrollPane itself is inside of a StackPane.
In the beginning I scale my pdf to fit the width of my ScrollPane. As a result of that the pdf-height doesn't fit the ScrollPanes height.
I already managed to zoom, by changing my scaleFactor when using the mousewheel. Unfortunately I can't zoom into a specific point.
I guess I have to change the ScrollPanes values depending on the mouse coordinates, but I just can't find the correct calculation. Can somebody please help me?

For example I tried

```
scrollPane.setVvalue(e.getY() / scrollPane.getHeight())
```

With this line of code my view just jumps up or down, depending on whether I click on the upper bound or the lower bound of my viewport.
I also understand that it has to behave like that, but I can't figure it out what has to be added/changed.

I use Jpedal to display my pdf

Hope you understand what I am looking for.
Tell me if you need more information.

**Edit:**

Here is a snipped of how I managed to drag.

```
    eventRegion.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
        dragStartX = e.getX();
        dragStartY = e.getY();
    });

    eventRegion.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e -> {                     
        double deltaX = dragStartX - e.getX();
        double deltaY = dragStartY - e.getY();

        scrollPane.setHvalue(Math.min(scrollPane.getHvalue() + deltaX / scrollPane.getWidth(), scrollPane.getHmax()));          
        scrollPane.setVvalue(Math.min(scrollPane.getVvalue() + deltaY / scrollPane.getHeight(), scrollPane.getVmax()));                 

        e.consume();
    });
```

I think zooming to the mouse position could be done in a similar way, by just setting the Hvalue and Vvalue.
Any ideas how I can calculate these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788184/javafx-8-dynamic-node-scaling) has JavaFX 8 code for a zoomable, pannable `ScrollPane` with zoom to mouse pointer, reset zoom and fit to width of a rectangle which can really be any `Node`. Be sure to check out the answer to the question to get `fitWidth()` to work correctly. I am using this solution for an `ImageView` now, and it is slick.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the pivot point? Because I don't really get what happens in setPivot() can you try to explain it to me?

Comment: Yes, it is a necessary method. It is effectively the same as `setTranslateX(getTranslateX() - x);` `setTranslateY(getTranslateY() - y);` `setScale(scale);` except it animates the translations so they look smoother.

Comment: Did I answer your question? Are you still having trouble? Can I help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

just for all related questions about **"zooming where the mouse is"**.

I had the same problem and I came up with the following code snippet.

```
public void setZoom(final double x, final double y, final double factor) {
    // save the point before scaling
    final Point2D sceneToLocalPointBefore = this.sceneToLocal(x, y);

    // do scale
    this.setScaleX(factor);
    this.setScaleY(factor);

    // save the point after scaling
    final Point2D sceneToLocalPointAfter = this.sceneToLocal(x, y);

    // calculate the difference of before and after the scale
    final Point2D diffMousePoint = sceneToLocalPointBefore.subtract(sceneToLocalPointAfter);

    // translate the pane in order to point where the mouse is 
    this.setTranslateX(this.getTranslateX() - diffMousePoint.getX() * this.getScaleX());
    this.setTranslateY(this.getTranslateY() - diffMousePoint.getY() * this.getScaleY());
}
```

The basic idea is to move the underlying Pane to that point where it was before scaling. Important is the fact, that we calculate the mouse position to the **local** coordinate system of the Pane. After scale we do this just another time and calculate the difference. Once we know the difference we are able to move back the Pane. I think this solution is very easy and straightforward.

My setup in JavaFX is following: I have a javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane as root for my javafx.scene.Scene. In the center I put a Pane. This will be the Pane where I act on (i.e. put other Nodes in..zoom, move..etc.) If anyone is interested in how I actually did it, just mail me.

Good programming!